# What is minimum system requirements to run electron apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, native, electron, system-requirements

I am deciding between options for building native desktop app.

I do not find any documentation for minimum system specs (OS/HW) for runtime of [electron](http://electron.atom.io) apps.
Can you help me out?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

based on [Electron supported platforms](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/support) and [Chrome minimum requirements](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?hl=en)

### OS requirements

**Windows**

- Windows 7 and later are supported, older operating systems are not supported (and do not work).
- Both x86 and amd64 (x64) binaries are provided for Windows. Please note, the ARM version of Windows is not supported for now.

**Mac**

- Only 64bit binaries are provided for macOS, and the minimum macOS version supported is macOS 10.10 (Yosemite).

**Linux**

- The prebuilt ia32(i686) and x64(amd64) binaries of Electron are built on Ubuntu 12.04, the arm binary is built against ARM v7 with hard-float ABI and NEON for Debian Wheezy.

Whether the prebuilt binary can run on a distribution depends on whether the distribution includes the libraries that Electron is linked to on the building platform, so only Ubuntu 12.04 is guaranteed to work, but following platforms are also verified to be able to run the prebuilt binaries of Electron:

- Ubuntu 12.04 and later
- Fedora 21
- Debian 8

---

### Hardware

About RAM and CPU, there are no information about that in Electron's docs, but Electron is based on Chromium, so it should need nearly the same requirements:

**Windows**

- An Intel Pentium 4 processor or later that's
  SSE2 capable
- 512 MB of RAM

**Mac**

- An Intel processor that's 64-bit
- 512 MB of RAM

**Linux**

- An Intel Pentium 4 processor or later that's SSE2 capable

Comment: That was my initial thought but I needed some documentation citation or experiential knowledge. I can't run VM's currently to test.

Comment: I updated my answer with some informations from Electron docs, but it does  not provide any information about hardware.